# Issues appending numpy arrays during for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm a bit lost at the moment. I correctly initialized an empty numpy array and I believe i'm using the `np.append` function correctly

```
Preds = np.empty(shape = (X_test.shape[0],10))

kf = KFold(n = X_train.shape[0], n_folds=10, shuffle = True)

for kf_train, kf_test in kf:

    X_train_kf = X_train.iloc[kf_train]
    Y_train_kf = Y_train.iloc[kf_train]

    dt = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2)
    dt.fit(X_train_kf, Y_train_kf)
    Preds = np.append(Preds,dt.predict(X_test))

    print Preds
```

Just some additional info:

- X_test has a shape of (9649, 24)
- (After running) Preds has a shape of (192980,)

At the of this loop, Preds should have a shape of (9649,10)

Any advice would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the updated solution

```
Preds = []
kf = KFold(n = X_train.shape[0], n_folds=20, shuffle = True)

for kf_train, kf_test in kf:

    X_train_kf = X_train.iloc[kf_train]
    Y_train_kf = Y_train.iloc[kf_train]

    dt = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2)
    dt.fit(X_train_kf, Y_train_kf)
    Preds.append(dt.predict(X_test))

Preds = np.vstack(Preds)
```

Comment: from the numpy.append docs: 'axis : int, optional

    The axis along which values are appended. If axis is not given, both arr and values are flattened before use'

Comment: and did you check the shape of dt.predict(X_test)?

Comment: It would be best to avoid using append. Instead just add each array to a python list and then use np.vstack or np.hstack to flatten them into a single array at the end.

Comment: @MaartenFabré it is (9649, ) I tried to change the axis to 1 but I get this error: `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`

Comment: @Erotemic, I'm not sure if i'm completely understanding your suggestion but I would like to keep Preds 2 dimensional. At the end of this, I would like to look at the prediction in each column and see what prediction occurs the most often. That will be easier to do if the array is 2D

Comment: what does axis=0 do? but I think @Erotemic's solution will be easier and easier to debug

Comment: @Erotemic you were correct, vstack does work. I will add the correct solution

Answer (score 1):

If `Preds` is (9649,10), then you can do one of 2 kinds of concatenation

```
 newPreds = np.concatenate((Preds, np.zeros((N,10))), axis=0)
 newPreds = np.concatenate((Preds, np.zeros((9649,N)), axis=1)
```

The first produces a (9649+N, 10) array, the second (9646,10+N).

`np.vstack` can be use to make the 2nd array is 2d, i.e. it changes `(10,)` to `(1,10)` array. `np.append` takes 2 arguments instead of a list, and makes sure the second is an array.  It is better for adding a scalar to a 1d array, than for general purpose concatenation.

Make sure you understand the shapes and number of dimensions of your arrays.

A good alternative is to append to a list

```
alist = []
alist.append(initial_array)
for ...
    alist.append(next_array)
result = np.concatenate(alist, axis=?)
# vstack, stack, and np.array can be used if dimensions are right
```

Appending to list, followed by one join at the end is faster than repeated concatenates.  Lists are designed to grow cheaply; arrays grow by making a new larger array.